# Keep secondary process running after main one closes

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

Using the `multiprocessing` library to run a second process, how can I keep that process running after closing the initial one? I swear it originally did that, and I had to enable the daemon option so that it would close properly, but now I can't seem to separate them.

Here's some simple code that has the problem. Hitting close on the main window will also close the second process, but as far as I'm aware that should only happen if daemon is set to True.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def background_process():

    #So you can see it eating the cpu
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Process(target=background_process)
    p.daemon = False
    p.start()
```

I'm aiming for the script to run on all platforms, so as the multiprocessing part is a big chunk of the code, I'd prefer to keep it fairly universal.

Comment: Always tag your quests with "windows", if you need windows specific answers. Normally one would assume that you are targeting a posix system.

Comment: Ah right thanks, I never thought of that. I'm ideally wanting it to run on all systems, so I'm trying to avoid making major parts specific to any operating system :)

Comment: Neither of these processes owns a window. Both processes are attached to a console (conhost.exe), which they use via standard I/O. The console owns the window, and it's hard-coded to terminate all processes attached to it when closed.

Comment: multiprocessing automatically kills all daemon processes, and otherwise waits for all non-daemon processes to exit. To bypass this you can use `os._exit(0)`, which exits Python immediately.

Comment: To detach the child process from the console, you should first dupe the standard streams to `nul`, e.g. `fd = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR);` `os.dup2(fd, sys.stdin.fileno());` `os.dup2(fd, sys.stdout.fileno());` `os.dup2(fd, sys.stderr.fileno());` `os.close(fd)`. Then free the console handle via `ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32').FreeConsole()`. Now the console can be closed without it killing your background process.

Comment: Cheers, that appears to work on the really simple script, i'll attempt to integrate it into the main one tonight :)  Should all of that work on all operating systems aside from the `ctypes` part, or do the other systems not have the same issue?

Comment: It appears that code stops working again after generating as an exe file (tried with and without `freeze_support` enabled), even when the exe still loads the console

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: Can't you just run a second instance of Python using Popen?

Comment: I'm needing the two processes to communicate via `Queue` (the main one runs many times per second and the background does the heavy lifting), I'm out at the moment so can't really check, but would popen work in that case?

Comment: `Queue` is nothing but an unnamed pipe that transfers [marshal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html)led data (well, it uses a shared secret, and an MAC to ensure the data is sane). Just implement that yourself using e.g. a local TCP socket. Pass the port to the child, and send yourself [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)d data. You won't get multiprocessing to work on all systems.

Comment: That sounds like a really good but very complex idea, I'll properly look into it after the other bits are finished, do you happen to know if you can set a timeout on the receiving end of the pipe?. I know multiprocessing works on linux anyway, not sure about mac though

Comment: Just had a thought, would `socket` work for that? I'm thinking the order could be `load main script > subprocess open background script (without console) > set background script to host > set main script to client`, does that sound about right? It would have the added bonus of working over a network I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`os.fork()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork):

```
from os import fork

child_pid = fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    '''This is the child process, i.e your background process'''
else:
    '''This is the parent process.'''
```

You can use [signals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill), [pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe), and [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair) (Unix sockets) to communicate.

multiprocessing.Process tries to make your life easier, but it seldom does. I would advise you not to use it at all.

Comment: Thanks, but it's for Unix systems only unfortunately, comes up with an `ImportError` on Windows. I'm using `Queue` from multiprocessing which is super useful, it's just `Process` which is causing quite a lot of hassle :P

Comment: Are you using windows 10? Then the Linux version of Python should work: http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-with-ubuntu-on-windows/

Comment: @Peter:  Yeah, Windows can't fork at all.  The Cygwin emulation of fork() is intense but has limited compatibility.

Comment: I'm attempting to make it run without effort on all operating systems to be fair (someone already got most of the linux version working), so probably best leaving it to the default python installation haha. The multiprocessing module works but I'm just needing it to not quit instantly which is proving a little annoying.